# Jquery clone div for the first times, stop users for cloning more than 6 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

i am trying to create a clone div to an existing div. the clone is working and allow the user to clone the div by clicking the button. Now what i would like to be a validation where the user is only allowed to clone the div up to 6 times only and if possible display a message of " you are not allowed to add anymore item"

```
  <div id ="specdiv ">
         <fieldset class="fieldset">
              <legend class="legend">Question Specification</legend>
                 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferedAnswer)
        </div>
            <div class ="answerchoice1" id="">
         <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OfferedAnswer.AnswerText)




        </div>
                </div>

             </fieldset>


    </div>
 <button id="quesId" class="mini-button" type =" button">+</button>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        //$('.answerchoice1').before($('.answerchoice1').clone())
        var $target = $('.answerchoice1').find('div.editor-field:first');
        $target.clone().appendTo('.answerchoice1');
        var tID = $(this).attr(".answerchoice1").split(/ _/);
        //console.log($('.example-1').html());
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you are after:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        if($('.editor-field').length >= 6){
        alert('No more than 6!');
        return false;
        }
        //$('.answerchoice1').before($('.answerchoice1').clone())
        var $target = $('.answerchoice1').find('div.editor-field:first');
        $target.clone().appendTo('.answerchoice1');
        var tID = $(this).attr(".answerchoice1").split(/ _/);
        //console.log($('.example-1').html());
    })

})
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/on3kj4hp/

Hope it helps!